# .net packet capture: pcap.net vs sharppcap

Tags: .net, packet-capture, winpcap, packet-sniffers, pcap.net

interested in any comments anyone has around the various .net tools which can be used for passive packet capture. In terms of winpcap the choice seems to be between pcap.net and sharppcap. Another potential offering is Microsoft's [NetworkMonitor](https://connect.microsoft.com/site216) and I am sure there are others as well.

I have used ethereal/wireshark as a diagnostic tool occasionally over the years but that is the limit of my knowledge. I'm looking to automate the capture process and subsequent diagnostic processing. I am tending towards pcap.net at the moment but would like to hear from anyone who has used two or more of these tools and whether they'd recommend one over another. My preference would be for the simplest interface/shallowest learning curve. Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: @Daniel: I want to write code that sniffs packets

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use .NET 4 or willing to use older versions of [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdot.net), it is definitely the choice.
Pcap.Net is much more flexible and include many more features and is very easy to use.

Disclosure: I'm a developer in Pcap.Net.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've ended up using sharppcap because the dll references required for pcap.net wouldn't load into my project correctly. Expect it was my mistake but the sharppcap reference worked without fuss...

Comment: If you need any help with the library drop me an email, chmorgan@gmail.com

Comment: A way better idea, especially since Chris is already a member of Stack Overflow, is to ask a question here. Then, not only do you get your answer, but so can everyone else who encounters the same problem in the future! Everyone benefits.