# How to intercept packets sent by an application and check their header and content?

Tags: c#, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I'd like to know how can I intercept packets sent by a certain application and then to check what those packets contain.
I need some advice what to do because I've never done such a thing and I want to learn by myself.

Comment: Use something like [Pcap.net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/).

Comment: btw, can you let me know what `PACKETS` you are refering html, tcp or else ?

Comment: @HarshBaid No such thing as Html packets, HTTP perhaps.

Comment: @Nacereddine I don't know what you name it but it is useful to check http traffic in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) rather than using capture anything tool which can be complex to use and learn at start. :D

Comment: Http packets , for example a game launcher. I want to learn how to do it in c# not to use other programs. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### **[Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/)**

Pcap.Net is a .NET wrapper for WinPcap written in C++/CLI and C#.
It Features almost all WinPcap features and includes a packet interpretation framework.

### **[SharpPcap](https://github.com/chmorgan/sharppcap)**

SharpPcap is a cross-platform packet capture framework for the .NET environment, based on the famous pcap / WinPcap libraries. It provides an API for capturing, injecting, analyzing and building packets using any .NET language such as C# and VB.NET.

### [Comparision of Pcap.Net and SharpPcap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650754/pcap-net-vs-sharppcap)

### [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

It is used for network troubleshooting, analysis, software and communications protocol development, and education. And I think it is the most versatile packet sniffer I used till now.

### [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with
incoming or outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language. Recently Fiddler has been overtook by Telerik. But it is still free AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Pcap or sharppcap would help me . thanks

Comment: You can also use FiddlerCore from here http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore

Answer (score 5):

Some example of c# sniffer socket creation.

```
    mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw,
                           ProtocolType.IP);

    // Bind the socket to the selected IP address
    mainSocket.Bind(newIPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(cmbInterfaces.Text),0));

    // Set the socket options
    mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,  //Applies only to IP packets
                               SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, //Set the include header
                               true);                           //option to true

    byte[] byTrue = newbyte[4]{1, 0, 0, 0};
    byte[] byOut = newbyte[4];

    //Socket.IOControl is analogous to the WSAIoctl method of Winsock 2
    mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll,  //SIO_RCVALL of Winsock
                         byTrue, byOut);

    //Start receiving the packets asynchronously
    mainSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                            newAsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
```

Comment: This code is taken from - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C

Answer (score 2):

You can use Fiddler to see HTTP traffic http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/.

Alternatively Wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/ for more advanced stuff

Summary of Packet Analyzers here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer

More details of what you are trying to achieve would help us advise.