# sniff the data on a selected port - C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, wireshark, winpcap

I have one application running on specific port. I dont have access to this application but i know what it does. Now this application is listening on one specific port and process the data coming on that port

Now i have been assigned the task on logging all the packets received on that port with all the data details. I have used the wireshark and can apply the filter to check the data coming on that specific port. So i assume here that i have been stuck in creating this kind of snipping program so i can get all the data packet details. I have search the stack overflow and come up with

1. [Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C)
2. [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437620/how-to-intercept-packets-sent-by-a-application-and-check-what-they-have)

Now i have evalute the sample and can see that it gives me packets but it listens on all port of the system. Not on the specific port. Can someone help me to achieve my solution? Basically if i will listen to all port then there are lots of app/program running on server so it may get bottleneck. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

In MJsniffer.MJsnifferForm class you have ParseData method - at first step it converts received bytes to  IPHeader object, an then there a huge SWITCH-CASE on ProtocolType field. Inside that SWITCH there are TCPHeader or UDPHeader is created and added to TreeView on form - there you can filter packages by SourcePort/DestinationPort fields tcpHeader/udpHeader.

Also  if you are already familiar with WireShark, then you can easly switch to Pcap.NET wrapper(they use same packet capturing library - WinPcap)

Comment: Is there any way to directly check that port rather than gettign all data and filtering though it?