# Network packet interception

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question. Is it possible to intercept network packages that run from local program to a X.X.X.X network address using .Net? And then these packages receive programmatically and give the calling program? Maybe you know examples of articles that will help me write a program?

Comment: Look @ [Codeproject articale](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) for this.  It is a wrapper around the [WinPcap driver](http://www.winpcap.org/) that is used by applications such as [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

There is another library called [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page) which does the same thing.  There's a [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET) on this library.

I'm not sure of which one is better, but there are comparisons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650754/pcap-net-vs-sharppcap) and [here](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/219680).

AFAIK, there isn't a way to do it without a packet capture/interception driver.